# Haskell: memoization

Tags: haskell, recursion, memoization

I'm trying to relearn Haskell, after many years away and forgetting everything, and I find myself still confused my *memoization*. In particular, I'm trying to write a program to generate the number of derangements `D[n]` of `n` objects (permutations with no item in its original place); the numbers `D[n]` can be defined recursively by `D[1]=0`, `D[2]=1`, `D[n]=(n-1)(D[n-1]+D[n-2])`.

So this works:

```
der :: Int -> Integer
der n = lder !! n
  where lder = 1 : 0 : zipWith3 (\n d1 d2 -> n * (d1+d2)) [1..] lder (tail lder)
```

as does this (which is a bit clumsy as it requires three functions):

```
nder :: Int -> Integer
nder n = nderTab !! n

nderTab :: [Integer]
nderTab = [nderCalc n | n <- [0..]]

nderCalc :: Int -> Integer
nderCalc n
  | n == 0    = toInteger 1
  | n == 1    = toInteger 0
  | otherwise = toInteger (n-1) * (nder (n-1) + nder (n-2))
```

But this doesn't:

```
nders :: Int -> Integer
nders n = (map der [0 ..]) !! n
  where der 0 = 1
        der 1 = 0
        der n = (nders (n-2) + nders (n-1)) * toInteger (n-1)
```

You'll recognize this last as a copy of the standard memoized Fibonacci number function.  My function works, but isn't memoized, as it hangs on values larger than about 30.  Also, if I write this function to operate only on values greater than or equal to 1:

```
nders :: Int -> Integer
nders n = (map der [1 ..]) !! n
  where der 1 = 0
        der 2 = 1
        der n = (nders (n-2) + nders (n-1)) * toInteger (n-1)
```

it doesn't work at all. I'm curious to know what's wrong with these last two functions.

Comment: This is a scoping issue.  Try `nders = (map der [0..] !!)` instead, which indicates that `n` does not need to be known to evaluate the `map`  (The reason the compiler doesn't do this automatically is that it can create unwanted memory leaks .. which is what you are doing here, except that you want the memory leak ;-)

Comment: Many thanks!  Yep, that works perfectly.  These are fiddly matters I've yet to get my head around.  Curiously, the map needs to be defined on `[0..]`; if I define it on `[1..]` the function doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah that's because `!!` is zero-based.  The strategy hinges on the fact that `[0..] !! n = n` for all the `n`s we're interested in (because we need `map f [0..] !! n = f n`, so it had better work for `f = id`)

Answer (score 3):

With

```
nders :: Int -> Integer
nders n = (map der [0 ..]) !! n
  where der 0 = 1
        der 1 = 0
        der n = (nders (n-2) + nders (n-1)) * toInteger (n-1)
```

the `map der [0..]` part will be recomputed for any application of `nders`, especially including the recursive calls in `der`.

You can move out the definition of the tabulation so that it doesn't (syntactically) depend on `n`, which should do the right thing:

```
nders :: Int -> Integer
nders = (memoized !!)
  where 
    memoized = map der [0 ..]

    der 0 = 1
    der 1 = 0
    der n = (nders (n-2) + nders (n-1)) * toInteger (n-1)
```